# jQuery load function not working on binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bind "load" and "change" in jQuery code. 
My goal is: disable some field based on logic when page load.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    //Question 34.1
    jQuery('select#fever').bind('load change', function () {
        var drug_reaction = jQuery(this).val();
        if(drug_reaction== 1){            
            jQuery('input#fever_days').attr('disabled',false); 
            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').attr('disabled',false);     
            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').attr('disabled',false);
            jQuery('select#night_sweats').attr('disabled',false);       
        }else{
            jQuery('input#fever_days').val("");
            jQuery('input#fever_days').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').val("");
            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').val("");
            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#night_sweats').val("");
            jQuery('select#night_sweats').attr('disabled',true);       
        }
    });
 });
```

When I change fever dropdown , its working. But when page load, I fetch data from Database and this code not working:

```
var drug_reaction = jQuery(this).val();
        if(drug_reaction== 1){            
            jQuery('input#fever_days').attr('disabled',false); 
            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').attr('disabled',false);     
            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').attr('disabled',false);
            jQuery('select#night_sweats').attr('disabled',false);       
        }else{
            jQuery('input#fever_days').val("");
            jQuery('input#fever_days').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').val("");
            jQuery('select#character_of_fever').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').val("");
            jQuery('select#evening_raise_of_temparature').attr('disabled',true); 

            jQuery('select#night_sweats').val("");
            jQuery('select#night_sweats').attr('disabled',true);       
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`load` events fire on elements which load data from a URL (e.g. the whole page, `img` elements and `iframe` elements).

A select element doesn't load external data, and nor do any of its descendants. There is no load event.

Even if there was, it would have already loaded by the time the `ready` event fires.

Trigger the change event as part of your `ready` event handler instead.

```
jQuery('select#fever')
    .bind('change', function () { ... })
    .trigger("change");
```